# thread.sleep() not working in - selenium @After, in mobile mode

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to close the WebDriver after each run of `@Test`. but I don't want it to close right-away but wait a couple of seconds before it does. The obvious option is to use `Thread.sleep()`, but unfortunately since I run it in mobile mode (open chrome in mobile display, like do open using <kbd>F12</kbd> it doesn't work! the WebDriver is closing right-away and doesn't wait at all.

When I used `Thread.sleep()` in regular mode (desktop) it worked just fine, but not now. so my question is this: How can I make the WebDriver of mobile mode wait a few seconds before closing?

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception{

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driverWrapper_M.quit();
}
```

This is my init method (that's what activates the mobile mode)

```
public void init(){

    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Galaxy S5");
    Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
    remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
}
```

Comment: If the `quit()` method gets executed without the 3 seconds delay, the sleep must have been interrupted. Try and wrap the `Thread.sleep(3000)` in a `try-catch` block and print out the exception. There should be one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I did it and nothing was printed..

Comment: thread.sleep() wont work on mobile or appium

Comment: try this method `public void waitForScreenToLoad(AppiumDriver lDriver, WebElement element, int seconds){

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(lDriver,seconds);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}`